# I have some error can anyone help me in this

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'char [100]'
error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'const char*'
```

and I got the above two errors for these lines of codes

```
    string s1=asctime(localtime(&timetoday));;
    string r=s1.substr(4,6);
    ch=r;                        //char ch[100];(defined aleady)
    //1st error was in line just above this comment
    if(strcmp(r,"Dec 20")==0)
 //2nd error was in line just above this comment
    {
        cout<<"made my first try for creating this program";
    }
    else if(strcmp(r,"Dec 21")==0)
    {
        cout<<"Shortest day of the year";
    }
```

I'm trying to create a simple remainder program in C++ using code blocks.

Comment: may be from this line `ch = r;` , looks like you are mixing `C`and `C++`. `r` is `string` and `ch` is a `char`

Comment: `string`s have their own built-in comparison operators. Where possible go all in on `string` and use `string`s facilities.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated language tags. This question is about C++ with C++ code, so don't tag C.

Comment: As for your problem, get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and take some classes to learn C++ *properly*.

Comment: Simple example: https://ideone.com/WSSLGF

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the following line:

`ch = r;`

The variable `ch` is of type `char[100]`, the variable `r` is of type `std::string`. These types are not compatible, you cannot assign an `std::string` to a `char` array.

You probably want to write the following instead:

`strcpy( ch, r.c_str() );`

However, it would be simpler not to use C-style strings at all, and instead use `std::string` everywhere, like this:

```
string s1=asctime(localtime(&timetoday));;
string r=s1.substr(4,6);
if( r == "Dec 20" )
{
    cout<<"made my first try for creating this program";
}
else if( r == "Dec 21" )
{
    cout<<"Shortest day of the year";
}
```

Another mistake in your program seems to be that you are calling `strcmp` twice, once like this:

`strcmp(r,"Dec 20")`

And once like this:

`strcmp(ch,"Dec 21")`

The second one is correct, but the first one is wrong, as you must pass a C-style string (a `char` array), and not a C++ style string (a `std::string`). You probably meant to write `ch` instead of `r`. Alternatively, if you want to keep using `r`, you can write `r.c_str()` instead, which will return a C-style string. But, as already stated above, the best solution would probably be to use `std::string` everywhere and not use `strcmp` at all, as it is only intended for C-style strings.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR/MADAM YOU SOLVED MY 1st ERROR. THANK YOU
I CORRECTED MY MISTAKE.

Answer (score 1):

The code is incomplete, i.e. ch is not defined, but you probably want to use r.c_str() in the first call to strcmp, and in the 2nd case r.c_str() instead of ch.

Answer (score 0):

strcmp compares two cstrings(const char*), you are passing a std::string. try something like ``if(r == "Dec 20") ...```

Comment: THANK YOU SIR/MADAM YOU SOLVED MY 2nd ERROR. THANK YOU
I CORRECTED MY MISTAKE.

Answer (score 0):

`ch = r` you are mixing string with char array or `c with cpp` . Why not make your life easy you can use `std::copy` in this way

```cpp
 std::copy(r.begin(),r.end(),ch);
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `ch` is of kind `char[100]`, the variable `r` is of kind `std::string`. These sorts are not compatible, you can not assign an `std::string` to a char array

Comment: This answer adds nothing new to the answers already posted.